# How to delete a file after using find and grep to search for file?

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I'm using this command to search for a specific file:

```
find . -type f -name Client.php | xargs grep WARNING
```

I can't figure out how to add the delete command so that way the user is prompted before the delete command happens.

Comment: Which `find` versson do you use, GNU one? Try `find . -type f -name Client.php -exec grep -q WARNING {} \; -delete` (warning: deletes without asking).

Comment: @jimmij version 4.4.2

Answer (score 4):

You can't pipe to `xargs` here and rejoin the find, `find` can run commands like `grep` on its own.

The [`-exec` primary](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) runs a command for a file or files. It succeeds and continues processing the operands to the right only when the command itself exits with a successful result, so

```
find . -type f -name Client.php -exec grep -q WARNING {} \; -exec echo {} \;
```

will *print out* the path of every file named "Client.php" that contains "WARNING" inside it. You can change that second `-exec ... \;` to `-delete` to have it delete, or change the command to use `rm` or `mv` to deal with them.

---

The semicolons make sure only one file is checked at a time, and that we get this true-on-success behaviour:

> If the primary expression is punctuated by a <semicolon>, the utility *utility_name* shall be invoked once for each pathname and the primary shall evaluate as true if the utility returns a zero value as exit status.

The whole `-exec ... \;` is one chunk, so if you're using `-delete` you want to remove the semicolon along with `-exec` and the command.

---

I suggest running the command above *first* and making sure that it really does only include only the files you want before you actually delete them. However, a full delete-without-asking command would be

```
find . -type f -name Client.php -exec grep -q WARNING {} \; -delete
```

Proceed with caution!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FINDFILE=Client.php
if [[ $(find . -type f -name $FINDFILE | xargs grep "WARNING") ]] ; then
rm -i $FINDFILE
else
echo "File with warning not found."
fi
```

Place the script in your /usr/local/bin, chmod +x /usr/local/bin/scriptname.

Now you can execute it from anywhere at any time. *(It's also best to leave off the .sh extension)*

Comment: If a file with the name `Client.php` _anywhere_ under the current directory is found that contains the string `WARNING`, the `Client.php` in the _current_ directory is removed?

Comment: @Kusalananda That looks like what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec very nice solution! Thanks!

Comment: @music-code is it the answer, does something need clarification?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec No, I get what you did now

Comment: @music-code What is wrong, or what is it that you need done? Do you need it to be recursive or something?